# Using plt.show() to graph a component in python

Tags: python

I am trying to graph a component which is component[254] which has 16 nodes.
I am using the function plt.show() to view the graph. It is not showing up.
I am trying to understand how to graph it and compare it to average degree and density.
Any insights on the graphing and comparing.
Here is my code so far:

```
compA = components[243]
plt.show()
compB= components[155]
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please provide an example of the data you are trying to graph.

Comment: `plt.show()` shows an already plotted image. You have to plot your graph first. The actual plotting procedure depends on which module is used to represent graphs. For example, if your graph was created with `networkx`, then `networkx.draw()` or `networkx.draw_networkx()` would prepare the image.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling `plt.show()` you have to create a plot by, at a minimum, calling `plt.plot(x,y)` where `x` is the array of x-coordinates and `y` is the array of y-coordinates.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xdata = range(10) 
ydata = [x**2 for x in xdata]

plt.plot(xdata, ydata)
plt.show()
```

which produces the plot:
[image: Simple plot of y = x**2]